# why Google Maps is more popular than the other web mapping services?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any list of points that differentiating google maps and the other web mapping services like MapQuest,Yahoo Maps...etc?(In User perspective and Developer perspective)

Comment: also because It was ( if I am not wrong ) the first Big one with open API

Comment: According to wikipedia, google maps started out without an API and other users had to reverse engineer google maps. When it became successful, they started out their api http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps#Google_Maps_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In user perspective:**

1. Fast
2. Reliable information
3. GUI

**In developer perspective:**

1. Good Documentation
2. Wide support
3. Browser compatiability (IE7+, Firefox 2.0.0.8+, Safari 3+, Mozilla 1.7+, Opera 8.02+, Google Chrome 1+)
4. Free to use but has its own limit.

Check out this [**comparison table of web map services**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_map_services) for more information.